# How to configure cloud SQL with GKE using cloud sql proxy?

Tags: docker, go, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, cloud-sql-proxy

I am trying to set up a connection between `Google Cloud Postgres` and `Google Kubernetes Engine` using a `CloudSQL proxy`. If I check out the logs of both workloads:

I am getting:

```
2021-02-02T11:42:09.748706102Z2021/02/02 11:42:09 dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connect: connection refused
```

I am writing down all the steps that I performed with all the real file keywords or file names.

## Steps

1. Set up a `google cloud cluster` with 3 nodes.
2. Set up a `Postgres` instance of `Google Cloud SQL`. Add a new user `gothamuser` and password is `gothampass`: Running on 5432 port
3. Set up an `I am service` account through `gothamcity-gke@miles-789.iam.gserviceaccount.com` and saved the `config.json` file.
4. Link of `Docker file` [.1]
5. Build the container using `gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/miles-789/gothamcity:0.10 .`
6. Link of `Deployment.yaml` [.2]
7. Execute deployment file using `kubectl create -f deployment.yaml`
8. Link of `service.yaml`[3]
9. Execute service file using `kubectl create -f service.yaml`
10. Created cloud SQL instances using `kubectl create secret generic cloudsql-instance-credentials --from-file=cred.json=/Users/gotham/Downloads/cofig.json`
11. Created `cloudsql-db credentials using kubectl create secret generic cloudsql-db-credentials --from-literal=username=gothamuser --from-literal=password=gothampass`. Didn't mention the database name because I have to connect multiple databases.
12. Added `cloudsql-db-credentials` and `cloudsql-instance-credentials` in `psql.yaml` file
13. Link of `psql.yaml` file [4]
14. Execute this file using `kubectl create -f psql.yaml`
15. DB Configurations on `Go` project [5]

## Screenshot of kubectl commands

1 `kubectl get nodes`

[image]

2 `kubectl get pods`

[image]

## Mentioned Files

[1.] Docker

```
FROM golang:alpine AS build-env
ENV GOPATH /go
WORKDIR /go/src
COPY . /go/src/gothamcity

RUN cd /go/src/gothamcity && go build .

FROM alpine
RUN apk update && apk add ca-certificates && rm -rf /var/cache/apk*

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /go/src/gothamcity/gothamcity /app
COPY .env /app

EXPOSE 5432
EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT [ "./gothamcity" ]
```

[2.] Deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: gothamcity-backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: gothamcity
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: gothamcity
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: gothamcity-app
        image: gcr.io/miles-789/gothamcity:0.10
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        env:
          - name: PORT
            value: "8080"
```

[3] Service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: gothamcity
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: gothamcity
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
```

[4] psql.yaml

```
 apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: gothamcity-psql-proxy
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: gothamcity
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: gothamcity
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/miles-789/gothamcity:0.10
        name: gothamcity-app
        env:
        - namee: DB_HOST
          value: 127.0.0.1
        - name: DB_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: cloudsql-db-credentials
              key: username
        - name: DB_PASS
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: cloudsql-db-credentials
              key: password
        - name: DB_NAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: cloudsql-db-credentials
              key: database
      - name: cloud-sql-proxy
        image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.17
        command:
          - "/cloud_sql_proxy"
          - "-instances=miles-789:europe-east1:gotham-miles-v1=tcp:5432"
          - "-credential_file=/secrets/config.json"
        securityContext:
          runAsNonRoot: true
        volumeMounts:
        - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
          mountPath: /secrets/
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
        secret:
          secretName: cloudsql-instance-credentials
```

[5] DB Configurations

```
package dataservices

import "os"

const (
    dbhost = "DBHOST"
    dbport = "DBPORT"
    dbuser = "DBUSER"
    dbpass = "DBPASS"
    dbname = "DBNAME"
    env    = "ENV"
)

func dbConfig(database string) map[string]string {
    var host = os.Getenv("DB_HOST")
    var user = os.Getenv("DB_USER")
    var password = os.Getenv("DB_PASS")
    var name = database
    var port = "5432"
    conf := make(map[string]string)
    conf[dbhost] = host
    conf[dbport] = port
    conf[dbuser] = user
    conf[dbpass] = password
    conf[dbname] = name
    return conf
}
```

I can't understand What am i doing wrong here. Is it a typo or I am missing some kind of configuration here.

Comment: According to [this document](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-kubernetes-engine#proxy-with-service-account-key), If connecting using private IP, you must use a VPC-native GKE cluster, in the same VPC as your Cloud SQL instance. Do you verify if the port 5432 open in gothamcity-psql-proxy? If you have an outbound firewall policy, make sure it allows connections to [port 3307](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/sql-proxy#troubleshooting) on the target machine.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was wrong? I have a very similar deployment and suspect it is because the DBHost is 127.0.0.1 but we are deploying multiple pods.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a private cluster?
If so you need to have SQL DB on same VPC (or have VPC peering) for your app to reach SQL DB

Or you need to setup Cloud NAT on your VPC for cluster to SQL DB to talk back

this can be useful

https://groups.google.com/g/google-cloud-sql-discuss/c/6lA0r6zRfeI/m/hr8mRt9AGgAJ

Comment: Thanks for your answer:

I did check the cluster-info and found out:

Networking
Private cluster is Disabled
VPC-native traffic routing is Enabled

is that correct?